# How to notice difference between simple present and present continuous?

Tags: présent

I am currently a beginner level French student. In continuation to this post [French present continuous vs English present continuous](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43487/french-present-continuous-vs-english-present-continuous), I am curious about how French speakers deduce the meaning behind the French present tense to be either simple present or present continuous?

I notice that French present tense can be translated into both forms, for example:

```
Je mange une pomme

CAN BE

I eat an apple OR I am eating an apple
```

I am learning French with English in mind, so I'm curious about how French speakers comprehend this while using it in day to day life?

I am a beginner in French language so it might be a trivial question for you all, but it's worth putting it out here to clear the concept for once and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike you, French speakers do not have English in mind so do not pay any particular attention to these tense values, given the fact both are expressed the same way. They don't constantly translate in their mind French to another language to grasp it.

Anyway, in general the context is enough to sort out what English tense would translate a French present. Without context, *Je mange une pomme* is more likely to be *I'm eating an apple* while *Je mange une pomme tous les jours* would be *I eat an apple a day*.

Note also that while the *être en train de* form is often reported to match the present progressive, its usage is by far more rare. We would only say *Je suis en train de manger une pomme* to emphasize an action in progress, like *Right now, I'm eating an apple*.

Answer (score 1):

In French there is no continuous present as in English, that is by means of using an auxiliary. Instead of an auxiliary French uses a verbal phrase which is conjugated and followed by the infinitive of the verb.

- Je suis en train de manger une pomme (*I am eating an apple*)
- Tu es en train de manger une pomme
- Il/elle est en train de manger une pomme
- etc.

[gymlish — The present progressive: être en train de (to be doing something)](https://www.gymglish.com/en/frantastique/french-grammar/the-present-progressive-etre-en-train-de-to-be-doing-something)

Comment: An addendum: if you're translating from English to French, at least 90% of the time you wouldn't translate *I am eating an apple* by *Je suis en train de manger une pomme* but by *Je mange une pomme.*

Comment: @PeterShor This is also a correct way to express the progressive, and it is certainly used more often.   I don't know precisely what contexts call for one rather than the other. I don't think there exists a perfect equivalence. In particular, if think you can always use the verbal locution, but I'd have to do some research to find out what cicumstances make for a preferable use of it.

Comment: (au mobile) Personne 1: Qu'est-ce  que tu fais? (What're you doing?) Personne 2:  Je bosse dans une librairie là (I'm working at a bookstore [right] now). Personne 1: Ah bon? Je pensais que tu étais en train de travailler chez toi. (You are? I thought you were working at home.) **Compare**: Personne 1: Ah bon? Je pensais que tu travaillais chez toi. (I thought you worked at home).